# unable to load the exact data onto dynamic populated table rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a table with data populated  from database, in table td i want to populate my selected data from my table with selectbox option.

WIth the following code i am only able to populate the select-box in each rows. But i am unable to show the exact values for each rows in the select box.

![Output in my current table as shoing in this image. All selected dropdown is general. It is not the exactly as it is in the db table]][1]

Please help me to solve this problem

in view inside `for each loop` i have kept this

`<div style=width:510px>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('display_id', $display_select_options,$fdisplay_id, 'class="selectbox" id="my_id"'); ?>
     </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the catch

**controller**

```
 for($i=1;$i<=11;$i++)
    {
      $query = $this->Booksmodel->getDisplay();
      // this will pass only one value means overwrite 
      //previous value of display id
      //$data['fdisplay_id']['value'] = $query['display_id'];   

      //use this
      $data['fdisplay_id'][] = $query['display_id'];
   }
```

**in view loop**

```
 define $i = 0 and in loop $i++;
    <div style=width:510px> 
          <?php echo form_dropdown('display_id', $display_select_options,$fdisplay_id[$i], 'class="selectbox" id="my_id"'); ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: You have mention `define $i = 0 and in loop $i++;`  how to write in php code.

Comment: if you are using for loop then its like this <?  for($i=0; $i < 11; $i++){$fdisplay_id[$i]} ?> foreach loop <? $i=0; foreach($results as $result){$fdisplay_id[$i];$i++} ?>

Comment: i applied as you explained in my view. But it is not working. Please check my above code  once again. i shown my code as title `NEW UPDATE INTO MY VIEW`

Comment: just do print_r($data['fdisplay_id']); die() in controller check are you getting values or not

Comment: i added `for($i=1;$i<=15;$i++)
    {
      $query = $this->Booksmodel->getDisplay(); 
      $data['fdisplay_id'][] = $query['display_id'];
      print_r($data['fdisplay_id']); die() ;
   }` in my controller. And i am getting output in browser only this `Array ( [value] => 0 [0] => 2 )`

Comment: i think you defined array outside before loop that's why showing value as part of your fdisplay_id use this outside loop $data['fdisplay_id'] = array();

Comment: Sorry! What do you mean by your above comment?

Comment: see your array has Array ( [value] => 0 [0] => 2 )  value starting index its should be Array ([0] => 2 )

Answer (score 0):

```
       // $fdisplay_id should be an associative array.
        //Here's an example to help you out

    $options = array(
              'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
            );

    $shirts_on_sale = 'xlarge'; 
    //for multiselect $shirts_on_sale = array('xlarge','large');

   echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, $shirts_on_sale);
```